# Gossip Skip Handshake vs mutual TLS

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have seen in a balance transfer example of hyperledger fabric, stating that, **the following setting skips the gossip handshake since we are are not doing mutual TLS**

Refer: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/balance-transfer/artifacts/base.yaml

```
# The following setting skips the gossip handshake since we are
# are not doing mutual TLS
- CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_SKIPHANDSHAKE=true
```

Question: What is the relation with mutual TLS to skipping the handshake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old and deprecated option not in use since v1.1. While doing a handshake and in case of mutual TLS enabled gossip also authenticated TLS certificated, this option for a while allowed to skip it. Now, it's deprecated and not in use anymore.